# What does QWebEngine.loadFinished.connect() do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


app = QApplication([])

view = QWebEngineView()
view.show()

url = 'http://gama-gama.ru/search/?searchField=titan'
view.load(QUrl(url))

#what does this function call do?
view.loadFinished.connect(lambda x: view.grab().save('img.jpg'))

app.exec()
```

What does the loadFinished function do? I know that it is a "signal" but calling view.loadFinished() says TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable.

Can I use view.loadFinished.connect(is_finished_function) to prevent the page from thinking its loaded until a certain bit of text is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loadfinished is a `QSignal`.

`QSignal` is a class that has implemented the following methods: `connect()`, `disconnect()` and `emit()`, this can only be an attribute of a class that inherits from `QObject`.

> **void QWebView::loadFinished(bool ok)**
>
> This signal is emitted when a load of the page is finished. ok will
>   indicate whether the load was successful or any error occurred.

In your case I think that you are using it to let you know when I completely load the page (with or without errors), at that moment you call the function:

```
 lambda x: view.grab().save('img.jpg')
```